# ajax not making api call in framework7 on build version

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, html-framework-7

I am trying to make an api call in my hybrid app using `framework7 Dom7`
Its working very fine when i am testing on browser,but when i [build online on phonegap](https://build.phonegap.com/apps) for android's `APK` on my phone.Rest all JS working fone on phonebut only ajax call is not getting fired.

```
$$('form.ajax-submit').on('submitted', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
myApp.showPreloader();
    var searchKey=$$("#search-key").val();
              $$("#track").text('API calling');
    $$.get("http://my/api/path/dev/apiv-1-0-2/students/"+searchKey,function(response){
             $$("#track").text('got the response');
});
});
```

I am getting til `API calling` but not the `GOT THE RESPONSE` message.

Answer (score 0):

you are adding jQuery or jQueryMobile library in header in your page..?

Comment: nothing,is it really needed ? framework7 cant be enough alone?

Comment: and yes i included http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js cdn file above my framework7.js even the ajax fail to call API.